What do associated fibre bundles have in common?
Two fibre bundles are said associated if they have isomorphic associated principal bundles. I understand that this means they are defined by the same transition functions, but still is there some more geoemetric intuition?
I have read that there is Čech cohomology involved….

I think this is true only if the associated fibre bundle arises from an effective group action on the standard fibre. For example on an oriented manifold, the (anti-)canonical line bundle is trivial, but it is still associated to the frame bundle which might not be trivial. This is because the canonical line bundle arises from the determinant representation which isn't faithful, so it detects only a quotient of the structure group.

Thanks for the observation
